# run time error 91 object variable not set

Tags: variables, excel, object, runtime-error, vba

When I get to the line

> oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items

I get a:

> run time error 91, object variable not set

The zip file is created and in the working folder as well as the files to be zipped. I've checked my variables and they are set and correct.

```
Sub Zip_genie()
    Dim FileNameZip, FolderName, oFolder
    Dim strDate As String, DefPath As String
    Dim oApp As Object

    DefPath = "c:\users\" & Environ("Username") & "\documents\Appraiser_Genie\working\"
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    ChDir DefPath

    FileNameZip = "report.zip"

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    'Create empty Zip File
    NewZip (FileNameZip)

    FolderName = DefPath
    Debug.Print (FolderName)
    Debug.Print (FileNameZip)
    'Copy the files to the compressed folder
    oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items

    'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
    On Error Resume Next
    Do Until oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.count = _
        oApp.Namespace(FolderName).items.count
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0

    'MsgBox "You find the zipfile here: " & FileNameZip

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full pathname of the zip file.

For example, instead of just:

```
FileNameZip = "report.zip"
```

Use:

```
FileNameZip = "c:\users\" & Environ("Username") & "\documents\Appraiser_Genie\target\report.zip"
```

...or wherever your report.zip file is